# I need to implement wildcard search using % on both ends, how can I improve performance?

Tags: sql, sybase

I will be implementing this in the sql side, so I would end up having something like

```
where company.name like '%:parameter%'
```

I've read before that this would then make it impossible for the DB to use the company.name index.

My question then would be, what other options do I have to minimize the performance degradation that this will introduce to the search? Please note that, this is client requirements therefore I don't have the option to not implement (even though I explained to them the performance consequence of this).

The application is using Sybase SE 12.5.3 (based on the driver used in DBArtisan 8.5.5)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know Sybase, but you could do something along the lines below:

- Create a second field, which is the reverse of the company name.
- Add an index on this new field
- Use the following where clause

  WHERE company_name like ':parameter%' or reverse_name like
     Reverse(parameter)+'%'

Hope this points you in a good direction

Comment: I just saw an article saying in DB2, it does that internally, keeping the reverse value of the column for the purpose when double-ended wildcard is ever used.

Comment: It works well for name searches, like find all people whose last name ends with SON.    Becomes indexed search for NOS% and is pretty fast

Comment: I'll try this and run some tests. Based on your experience, this is a good choice, did you always choose this approach for scenarios like this (or were there other options you considered)? I'm optimistic that this will address minimizing the degradation.

Comment: I've used this technique for years... I actually thought of it when a book author said he couldn't think of a practical use for the Reverse() function in SQL. I've tried other approaches, building secondary look up tables in the past, but this approach works best for me

Answer (score 1):

You're dead right, that *is* a performance killer.

One method we've used in the past is to store all possible company names in a separate table, referring back to the main table. This is your classic time/space trade-off for optimisation.

In other words, let's say you have two companies in your main table, `ICBM` and `Microsloth`.

What you can do is to create *another* table containing the following:

```
TextSegment    varchar(?) indexed
ActualCompany  varchar(?)
```

and populate it as follows:

```
TextSegment  ActualCompany
-----------  -------------
ICBM         ICBM
CBM          ICBM
BM           ICBM
M            ICBM
Microsloth   Microsloth
icrosloth    Microsloth
crosloth     Microsloth
rosloth      Microsloth
osloth       Microsloth
sloth        Microsloth
loth         Microsloth
oth          Microsloth
th           Microsloth
h            Microsloth
```

Then, when you're looking for companies that are like `%slo%`, you can use:

```
select ActualCompany from LookupTable where TextSegment like 'slo%'
```

That allows you to use the index for that table more efficiently that with `%...%` on the other table.

Now, keep in mind you will need triggers on the original table to ensure the lookup table is consistent. And this will take a fair bit of space (depending on your data) but one thing I've noticed is that few people complain about how big their databases are, most problems are with speed.

The *time* impact of maintaining the separate table is usually not too bad since thevast majority of databases are read far more often than written. This method moves the cost from the select to the insert/update, where it can be amortised quite well.

Answer (score 0):

The possibility exits that an index could potentially be used, but its highly unlikely (see [this comment](http://dbaspot.com/sybase/421292-like-operator-not-using-indexes.html#post1405332)).  If possible, I would query based on another indexed field, and then sub-select against those results, to at least avoid a full table scan.