# Is this a correct way to allow wildcard search for a user?

Tags: java, sql, security, wildcard, parameterized-query

Given a textbox name for example, the user requirement wants to be able to do a wildcard search (such as contains, starts with, ends with).

Is it ok to accept the sql wildcard characters ('%' and '_') as input as long as I am still using parameterized query in the backend (Java)? Effectively, allowing the user to build his own regular expression which is what the user's requirement is all about.

Example:

1. User types in the

   ```
   textbox = '%are%'
   ```
2. This parameter is feed to the backend as such:

   ```
   public class PersonDaoImpl {

           public List<Person> search(String name){//name gets the value from textbox w/ sql wildcards
           Query q = mgr.createNativeQuery('select * from Person where name like :name'); //default to always use like since expecting searchkey with sql wildcards    
           q.setParameter('name', name);//gives the input from the screen
           return q.getResultList();
           } 
   }
   ```
3. The result set would include people with names 'Waren', 'Jared', 'Clare', 'Blare' as expected since user provided a regular expression.

With the SQL Parameterize Query, I can ensure that I won't be allowing SQL Injection. This implements the user requirement for wildcard search, but perhaps does it violate anything that I may have missed?

UPDATES:
Just found out that Google allows wildcard too, from their [help page](http://www.google.com/support/websearch/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=136861&rd=1).

Comment: I'm not sure how :name will be interpreted in the sql..YOu may have to write like below 'select * from Person where name like ' + '\'' + name + '\'' ...

Comment: I would suggest user should pass %are% instead of '%are%' given that you need quotes always, you can write code that part...

Comment: Edited my question and added the missing line of code, q.setParameter('name', name) which will replace the :name in the query with the value of the variable name.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, it violates the fact that the user needs to know (or be told) how to construct SQL "LIKE" syntax, but that's all. You could end up with a slow query this way, in that it won't usually be able to use an index, but I wouldn't be concerned in terms of security or correctness.

Comment: Thanks for the comment with regards to security or correctness.

Comment: Additionally, I was thinking along the lines on how Jira Issue Navigator allows advanced searching by allowing the user to provide expressions http://confluence.atlassian.com/display/JIRA/Advanced+Searching. But of course, this wildcard search that I have is nothing close to flexibility/complexity as the JIRA advanced search.

Answer (score 2):

It's "safe", but probably not a good idea, for two reasons:

1. It's probably not the best ui design to require your users to know sql syntax for this.
2. It's *horrible* for performance: these queries often can't use your indexes, so they are slow to execute. And they require a lot of cpu time to compare all that text, so they add a lot of load (disproportionate to the already high execution time) to your server.  You want a solution that relies on a full-text index instead.

Comment: On no. 2, the client wants a 'contains' search which is actually '%searchkey%'. I have informed client about the performance due to this, its been considered and the functionality outweighs the performance. I do plan to add some index as described here in this answer/question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7116094/i-need-to-implement-wildcard-search-using-on-both-ends-how-can-i-improve-perfo/7116118#7116118.

Comment: @Carlos - you missed the point. Sql Server has a function called CONTAINS() that does exactly what your client wants, without the performance penalty.

Comment: Good point, I am not aware of that function. I'm using Sybase, will try to see if it has something similar. I suppose if the user wants 'starts with' and 'ends with' then it would be a function call to startsWith or endsWith if there are such existing functions?

Answer (score 0):

<strike>I am curious, how does the `name` parameter end up getting set in the request? What platform is this?</strike> (OP missed `setParameter` earlier)

As  you noted  the user need to know the wild-card syntax i.e. the use of `%`, `_`, etc. A more popular approach is to just get the string from the username, along with an option for 'exact match'/'starts-with'/'anywhere-in-name'. If you go that route you will also be able to execute a more efficient query in the first two cases.

EDIT:

If the customer insists on `contains` query then I think  your current approach of requiring the end-user to input a pattern better then converting the input string to pattern by putting `%` around it.

This is because the users will still have the option of *not* adding (or selectively adding) the `%` to the search string, resulting in faster query execution. For example:

- If the user enter search string `Don` the query is `select ... from ... where name like 'Don'`. The RDBMS will most likely use the index on name.
- If the user enter search string `Don%` the query is `select ... from ... where name like 'Don%'`. The RDBMS will still quite likely use the index on name.
- If the user enter search string `%Don` or `%Don%` then the index cannot be used.

Comment: I missed the line of code q.setParameter('name', name); I have edited the question to reflect this, thanks for seeing that. This is in Java, it uses PreparedStatements underneath for Parameterized Query, where :name can be replaced with a value by doing the line of code I just added.

Comment: Ok :) Looking at your other comments here, if the customer always wants "contains" query then you might as well put the `%` around the input. On the other hand, allowing user to input it allows user to enter `term`, `term%`, `%term` or `%term%` which can result in faster query execution.

Comment: Yes, I would like to allow the user to be able to build his regular expression, he/she can even do something like this '%ap%zel' to get 'Rapunzel'. :)